# Set Cookie with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cookies, http-headers

I'm using **WordPress** on an **Apache** server & would like to use my **.htaccess** to set a cookie when someone first lands on my site.

If possible I'd set **TWO** Cookies to:

1. store the full URL
2. store the value in a parameter in the URL (e.g. *teamname*)

Ordinarily in PHP, I'd just have:

```
function set_user_cookie() {
    $url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['LandingPageURL'])) {
        setcookie('LandingPageURL', $url, time()+2678400, "/");
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'set_user_cookie');
```

However we've been noticing issues with caching so I wonder if it's possible to achieve this within my ***.htaccess*** instead.

Example URL: *[www.example.com/?teamname=Chicago+Bulls](http://www.example.com/?teamname=Chicago+Bulls)*

Comment: do you have a redirect in your .htaccess ?

Comment: @MaxMuster I don't have a redirect in there.

Comment: "However we've been noticing issues with caching so I wonder if it's possible to achieve this within my .htaccess instead." - Browser cache? Or server-side caching within WordPress itself? Setting this with `.htaccess` is not going to make any difference to the browser cache - if that is what you are referring to. (?)

Comment: See this article on how to set cookies using `mod_rewrite` in htaccess https://helponnet.com/2019/05/23/set-cookies-htaccess/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use something *like* this. this stores the full URL in a cookie called LandingPageURL .

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
// if the cookie "LandingPageURL" is not set 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*LandingPageURL.*$ [NC]
// then set it ...
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [co=LandingPageURL:$1:.example.com:2678400:/]
```

you probably want to use options like `HttpOnly` and `Secure` for your cookie

there is also another method to set a cookie in .htaccess that goes like this :

```
<If "%{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*LandingPageURL.*$">
    Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$  $1;SameSite=None;Secure;HttpOnly
</If>
```

if you want to read the cookie with php you can go like this

```
<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE['LandingPageURL'])) {
  error_log ("Cookie named 'LandingPageURL' is not set  in ".__FILE__." #".__LINE__);
} else {
  error_log("Cookie 'LandingPageURL' is set in ".__FILE__." #".__LINE__);
  error_log("Value of Cookie is: " . $_COOKIE['LandingPageURL'] );
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. Where would I be able to see this has been set correctly in the browser?

Comment: I do not understand the question , you can use the "inspect element" in "firefox", or the "inspect" option in "edge"

Comment: In Chrome, I checked 'Application' > 'Cookies' but don't see LandingPageURL listed in the Cookies :(

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Do you know how I output the Cookie value on my page to confirm it's being set correctly?

Comment: If the browser has cookies turned off then would this cookie still be readable in the php of that "LandingPageURL"??

Comment: @ermSO nope, since the browser must transmit the set cookie for the php page to read it